# Titanium.Map.View is deprecated, but link to new module does nowhere #appcelerator

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules, appcelerator-titanium

The [titanium map page](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Map.View) shows that the view is deprecated and points to the ti.map add-on module which is linked [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/Modules.Map) but does not have updated information for the map module.

There also is no way to search the page linked from the "deprecated" page to find what changed. So is the module deprecated or not, and if it is, what is the right page to find the methods and notations to use the map module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the ti.map moudule from [git](https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.map/releases)

And please refer the appcelerator docs for using the map.

[Android](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Map)

[iPhone](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/iOS_Map_Kit)

Comment: ti.map ships with the Titanium SDK. You shouldn't have to download anything. Just follow the guides that Suraj linked to.

Comment: Since the page linking and references in documentation were already wrong, I wasn't sure what to use. When will the links be fixed? I already found the links Suraj pointed to, but since the docs were not linked properly as indicated in my original message, I didn't know if I was using the correct ones. Since my app works and I'm using the links Suraj suggested, I'll assume that I stumbled onto right doc in spite of the links in my original post not being helpful - and I'll mark this solved. Thanks!

Comment: @petguy thanks of spotting that the links to the docs of the module do not work. I'll get it fixed asap: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIDOC-2441